# get() takes no keyword arguments : Django tutorial with different models

Tags: python, django

[image: The Error Message]

Here is my gambling view in views.py

```
def gambling(request, profile_id):
        Profile = get_object_or_404(profile, pk=profile_id)
        coin = get_object_or_404(Coin, pk=profile_id)
        try:
            selected_choice = coin.Face.get(pk=request.POST['name'])
        except (KeyError, Coin.DoesNotExist):
            # Redisplay the question voting form.
                return render(request, 'gamble/detail.html', {
                'Profile': Profile,
                'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
            })
        else:
            selected_choice.Face
            selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('gamble:results', args=(profile.id,)))
```

Here is the form in detail.html

```
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'gamble:gambling' Profile.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in coin.Face %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"> {{ choice }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}   

<input type="submit" value="flip" />
</form>
```

Here is my code for the Models profile and coin in models.py

```
# Create your models here.
class profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(default='description default text')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class  Coin(models.Model):
    #choice = models.ForeignKey(BetAmount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="...")
    flip = randint(0,1) 
    Heads =0
    Tails =1
    Face ={
    "Heads": Heads,
    "Tails": Tails 
    }

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text 
    def flipped(self):
        return self.flip
```

I keep getting the error about .get(), even though I am passing the form name, I am not sure if it has to do with the Coin object itself, clarity on the matter would help.
Is there something I am missing in the Coin model, or is the problem still in detail.html, I seem to have written code as close to the tutorial example as possible.

Comment: Post the full error message verbatim. Don't paraphrase.

Comment: The traceback will *tell* you whether it has to do with the Coin object. Post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coin.Face` is a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), not a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api):

```
Face = {
    "Heads": Heads,
    "Tails": Tails
}
```

And a the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) - `get(key[, default])` - does indeed not take any keyword arguments, but only a `key`, and - optionally - a default return value, both as positional arguments.

```
coin.Face.get('Head', coin.Heads)  # for instance
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.
What should I do to get the Face from the POST form then ?

Comment: Assuming the face is a string (`'Heads' or 'Tails'`) in  `POST['Face']`, you could do: `selected_choice = coin.Face.get(request.POST['Face'], coin.Heads)` where

Comment: This seems to go into the exception and gives me my error_message.